# Copying alhpanumeric chars in C

Tags: c, pointers, string

I have a char array of text, want to store the alphanumeric lowercase value in a pointer array. ie mystr should point to a char[] of "50sometexthere"

```
char[] myline = " 50 Some Text  Here ";
char *mystr = (char *)malloc(128 * sizeof(char));

char *tmp = myline;

while (*tmp != '\0'){
 if (isalnum(*tmp))
  strcat(mystr,(char*) tolower(*tmp));
 tmp++;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output/error do you get?

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()`. http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *myline = " 50 Some Text  Here ";
char *mystr = (char *)malloc(128); //sizeof char is always 1

char *tmp = myline;
char *tmpdest = mystr;

while (*tmp != '\0'){
 if (isalnum(*tmp))
  *tmpdest++ = tolower(*tmp); //this line is changed!
 tmp++;
}

*tmpdest = '\0';
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Need to get my head round these pointers, as I sort of see whats happening

Answer (score 2):

The function `tolower` returns an integer and you are wrongly casting it to `char *`.

The best way to do this is to copy alphanumeric characters from the source array into the destination array

```
char myline[] = " 50 Some Text  Here "; // put the [] after the variable.
char *mystr = malloc(128);

char *tmp = myline;
char *destPtr = mystr;

while (*tmp != '\0'){
 if (isalnum(*tmp)) {
   *destPtr++ = *tmp;
 }
 tmp++;
}
*destPtr = 0;  // terminating nul character.
```

If you really want to use `strcpy`, you need to initialize your destination string to an empty string and make the character to be copied part of a character array and append that array to the destination string:

```
char myline[] = " 50 Some Text  Here "; // put the [] after the variable.
char *mystr = malloc(128);

char *tmp = myline;
mystr[0] = 0;  // initialize the destination string.
while (*tmp != '\0'){
        char str[2] = {0}; // temp string of size 2.
        if (isalnum(*tmp))
                str[0] = tolower(*tmp); // put the char to be copied into str.
                strcat(mystr,str);      // append.
        tmp++;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use this approach in real code, you will want to ensure that you don't overrun the allocated 128 bytes at `mystr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the cast in the strcat call.

**almost always a cast, in `C`, is wrong**

`strcat` takes 2 pointers to char, you're supplying a pointer to char and an int (wrongly cast to pointer to char).

Comment: How would i convert to lowercase though without returning an integer?

Comment: @Igor K: as you see from Armen's answer, you don't use the integer for string functions. You need to find another way (his way is pretty good).